# Tobit regression in R

Tags: r, regression, package

I am doing Tobit Regression in R, cause my dependent variable is censored at 0.
I have panel data, for 6 years, 107 companies, 606 observations. 
I use package `CensReg`.

I have imported my database(T1).

I use pdata.frame to specify the structure of my panel data. Like:

```
mydata<- pdata.frame (T1, index = c("firm", "year"))
```

Afterwards:

```
Tob <- censReg(formula=Imp ~ Bath + CEOTurnover + ChangeOCF + E + Sales + ROE + GTA + Size , data = mydata, method="BHHH")
```

( like explained here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censReg/vignettes/censReg.pdf)

I got error message:

```
Warnmeldung:
In log(rEff$ercomp$sigma$id) : NaNs wurden erzeugt
```

> summary(Tob)

Call:
censReg(formula = Imp ~ Bath + CEOTurnover + ChangeOCF + E + 
    Sales + ROE + GTA + Size, data = mydata, method = "BHHH")

Observations:
         Total  Left-censored     Uncensored Right-censored 
           606            469            137              0

Coefficients:
Fehler in printCoefmat(coef(x, logSigma = logSigma), digits = digits) : 
  'x' must be coefficient matrix/data frame

> 

What could be the problem or would you suggest using other package.

Comment: It appears you are attempting to use a name for the varaible on the LHS that has a space in it. Putting spaces in R names is possoble but very unwise. Do you really think we can offer specific advice without a full description of `MYDATA`?

Comment: Can you do this so that we can use your data `dput(MYDATA1)` and paste the result in your question as MYDATA1?

Comment: Sorry, i am new to statistics and R. Formula is : Tob <- censReg(formula=Imp ~ Bath + CEOTurnover + ChangeOCF + E + Sales + ROE, data = Tob, method=”BHHH”).  Dependent variable Imp is : firm i’s reported goodwill impairment loss (reflected as a positive number) for period t, deflated by total assets at the end of period t-1. Other variables are ratios and calculated using firm's different financial numbers.  Hope the information is sufficient now. Thank you. @42-

Comment: Use the [edit] feature to include relevant material for your question. You should NOT use comments for that purpose. Post the results of `summary(Tob)`.